# VirtualBox Error, Storage:Settings, Guest Additions

Tags: linux, virtualbox

VirtualBox 5 on LinuxMint17.2
Trying to attach Guest additions (in Storage:Settings) for Win7 32bit guest to an empty optical drive.

I've done this successfully before for a Win7 64bit guest, but now cannot replicate the attachment on this guest either.

Details:
Controller:IDE (PIIX4)
Win7Ult32.vhd (Hard Disk       IDE Primary Slave)
Empty         (Optical Drive   IDE Secondary Slave)

Error message:

> Failed to open the disk image file /home/admin1/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.10-104061.vbox-extpack.
>
> Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/admin1/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.10-104061.vbox-extpack' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
> Component: MediumWrap
> Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
> Callee: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
> Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

Added: VirtualBox is installed on the LinuxMint host and the Guest additions work with the Win7 64bit guest.
My problem is that I cannot attach Guest additions to the Win7 32bit guest.

Comment: Is this question *about* Linux, or is it *about* VirtualBox (in a configuration with a Linux host and a Windows guest)? If the latter, it might be better on [SU].

Comment: Do you have `virtualbox-ext-pack` installed in the host?